# Find the table that a paragraph is in

Tags: vba, ms-word, paragraph

I am using VBA to read through a Microsoft Word docx using code like this:

```
For Each P In WD.Paragraphs 
    Temp = P.Range.Text
    If P.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    'Other stuff done here
Next P
```

There are a number of tables mixed into the documents and it reads the cells of them as paragraphs.  I want to get the rows and columns of whatever table the current paragraph is in.  Ideally, that would be a reference to the table itself.  I also know you can iterate through tables like this:

```
For Each T In WD.Tables
    Rcount = T.Rows.Count
    Ccount = T.Columns.Count
    'temp = T.Cell(R, C).Range.Text 'can get individual cell info like this
Next T
```

My first thought was to compare the text of the paragraph to the text of the table cells to try and find a match, but the cell may be empty so it's not a sure thing.  I'm not able to find an answer by searching; possibly because word, paragraph, and table are such common terms.

Comment: Try `Set oTable = P.Range.Tables(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Tim's method correctly finds a reference to the table:

```
Set oTable = P.Range.Tables(1)
```

or for just the rows and columns:

```
R = P.Range.Tables(1).Rows.Count
C = P.Range.Tables(1).Columns.Count
```